# swift coredata fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, core-data

```
for result in groups{
        let tmp = result.subject
        print("groups subject is \(tmp)")
}
```

I get `groups subject is MyGroupsData`

And I want to use in `tableView cellForRowAtIndex`

```
        var channel : myEntity?
        groupsData = groups[indexPath.row] as? myEntity
        dataSubject = groupsData!.subject
        print("groups subject is \(dataSubject)")
```

It shows `groups subject is nil`

reason : `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if let subject = groupsData?.subject {
dataSubject = subject
}
```

The problem is that groupsData is nil and you are trying to get a value out that does not exist.

Comment: failure....but it's strange. I can get data from `for in`,
but  fail in second function

Comment: Is the indexPath.row causing the groups array to access a value that is out of its bounds?